# Arrange tabs in Visual Studio without mouse

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 on dual monitor configuration, having main window with code on primary monitor, and other window with code on secondary monitor. Is there a command that can be be used with keyboard shortcut so that i move .cs file opened in one window to the other. I know that i can drag and drop tabs with mouse, but that is too slow and clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

I used my tool [FeinCtrl](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2c3354bd-8efd-4ea7-9099-a5fd80ca4185) and found the following commands related to document arrangement:

- Window.MoveToMainDocumentGroup
- Window.MovetoNextTabGroup
- Window.MovetoPreviousTabGroup

Unfortunately, dragged-out documents create separate top-level windows that appear to be non-addressable (you can move them back home).
Of course, you can bind those commands to some keyboard shortcuts, but that's not exactly what you were asking.

Comment: Window.MoveToMainDocumentGroup is 50% of what i need, this will move document to main window, what remains is to move document to some other DocumentGroup. But I don't need third party control to browse and assign commands, you can do all from VS default Keybord menu.